# (+)= "plus equal" operator in SQL statement

Tags: sql, operators

I have the following sql statement in php.
What does "(+)=" plus-equal operator mean in an SQL statement?
e.g.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM multimedia multi, titles title where title.id(+)=multi.title";

?>
```

Comment: what SQL server are you using?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I use an Oracle server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is old Oracle syntax for a left outer join.  It is better written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM multimedia multi left outer join
     titles title
     on title.id = multi.title;
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm) is documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

That's an Oracle style Outer Join. The equivalent ANSI join is:

```
select *
  from multimedia multi
  left join titles title
    on title.id = multi.title
```